# Copying all files of a directory to one text file in python

Tags: python, file

My intention is to copy the text of all my c# (and later aspx) files to one final text file, but it doesn't work.

For some reason, the "yo.txt" file is not created.

I know that the iteration over the files works, but I can't write the data into the .txt file.

The variable 'data' eventually does contain all text from the files . . .

*******Could it be connected to the fact that there are some non-ascii characters in the text of the c# files?

Here is my code:

```
import os
import sys

src_path = sys.argv[1]
os.chdir(src_path)

data = ""
for file in os.listdir('.'):
    if os.path.isfile(file):
        if file.split('.')[-1]=="cs" and (len(file.split('.'))==2 or len(file.split('.'))==3):
            print "Copying", file
            with open(file, "r") as f:
                data += f.read()


print data

with open("yo.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write(data)
```

If someone has an idea, it will be great :)

Thanks

Comment: I've tested your code and works well, do you have permission to write in the directory you are using it?

Comment: What is the exact command line string you are using to call your script?

Comment: are you looking for the file in the directory of the python script? It won't go there because you changed the working directory so the `yo.txt` will appear in the same folder as the files you were reading.

Comment: The command is : copyPro.py C:\temp\project - should not have a problem with it. @BrendanAbel

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen You are defenetly right :( Stupid of me, It is working lol

Comment: Does someone of you know about a way in which I can copy the text of the code (the project is written in Visual Studio) in a way that it will remain with the special colors and indentation that Visual Studio offers?

Answer (score 0):

You have to ensure the directory the file is created has sufficient write permissions, if not run

```
  chmod -R 777 .
```

to make the directory writable.

Answer (score 0):

```py
import os

for r, d, f in os.walk(inputdir):
    for file in f:
        filelist.append(f"{r}\\{file}")

with open(outputfile, 'w') as outfile:
    for f in filelist:
        with open(f) as infile:
            for line in infile:
                outfile.write(line)
        outfile.write('\n \n')
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and/or *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.